# How to stop loading specific HTML element? (Need to load videos based on browsing devices)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I need to load the videos based on screen size or devices (mobile and desktop)

I have same video suitable for mobile and desktop (I'm using Jinja templating).

In current scenario, both are getting loaded which slows down page loading speed

Please suggest ways to overcome this
I was trying to load them using window.innerWidth
can we have more efficient solution here?

html file

`

```
  <div class="video-bg-desktop">
    <video id="background-video" autoplay loop muted playsinline poster="{{ img.url }}"
      class="header-new__video">
      <source src="{{ video_mp4 }}" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="{{ video_webm }}" type="video/webm">
      <img src="{{ img.url }}" class="no-video-image">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="video-bg-mobile">
    <video id="background-video" autoplay loop muted playsinline poster="{{ img.url }}"
      class="header-new__video">
      <source src="{{ video_mp4_mobile }}" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="{{ video_webm_mobile }}" type="video/webm">
      <img src="{{ img.url }}" class="no-video-image">
    </video>
  </div>`
```

Comment: have you tried `CSS media Queries ` ?

Comment: @HansakaSandaruwan CSS can only affect once it gets loaded, to be precise I dont want to load both of them and then remove

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using plain old HTML, as mentioned above, you can add a CSS rule based on screen size.

A more specific solution in javascript would be to create a .js file that renders a particular page based on the browser used by the user. In your app.get() method you can add a callback that can be copied from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/, a website that includes callbacks for several other languages.

Comment: well, my-site is responsive to all screen size devices.
I have two separate videos, for mobile and desktop and I need them to load according to devices preference
I'm only concern about the this video element which now loads both videos, no matter where you load the site

Comment: Then it's best to add a javascript page with an if statement in the get method callback that checks what kind of browser is sending the request

Comment: I get it, I should use conditions to select if its mobile or desktop
but need the next logic,
we can also use conditional (window.innerWidth > mobile_width) but whats next?
if we left HTML untouched, should I remove class or scr attribute
brief coding answer will be appreciable

Comment: It all depends on the language you're using. In javascript with express and ejs you would require the express module and name it (for example app) and do:
app.get("link to video page", function(req,res) {req.render("the page which contains your video")})
Then that page would ideally be in ejs which would allow you to add the js if statement around your html

Comment: ejs is ypur friend in combining html and js

Answer (score 0):

Well, here I find out solution using javascript into HTML file

What I do is just use Jinja variables use in javascript and set the src attribute empty by default

It will load video conditionally, according to type of device mobile or desktop

NOTE:make sure it should below the HTML code as the classes and its elements should load first otherwise it will throw an error

```
(function () {
const bgv = document.querySelector(".video-bg-desktop");
const bgvMobile = document.querySelector(".video-bg-mobile");

if (window.innerWidth > 850) {
  const children = bgv.children[0].children;

  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
    if (children[i].type === "video/mp4") {
      children[i].src = "{{ video_mp4 }}";
    }
    if (children[i].type === "video/webm") {
      children[i].src = "{{ video_webm }}";
    }
  }
} else {
  const children = bgvMobile.children[0].children;

  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
    if (children[i].type === "video/mp4") {
      children[i].src = "{{ video_mp4_mobile }}";
    }
    if (children[i].type === "video/webm") {
      children[i].src = "{{ video_webm_mobile }}";
    }
  }
}
})();
```